# Java : call an API 200 times in parallel with no return expected

Tags: java, parallel-processing, executorservice

I'd like to call a REST API 200 times but I'm not sure of doing it the right way:

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(200);

for (i = 0 ; i<200 ; i++) {
    if (check == true) {
        es.submit() -> callTrueAPI();
    } else {
        es.submit() ->callFalseAPI();
    }

    es.shutdown;
```

Is it the right way to do it ?

Comment: Does it have to be called using Java?  There are tools like https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/ab.html to facilitate it.

Comment: Now that I have indented the code correctly, maybe it is a bit clearer?

Comment: yes it has to be in java.

Answer (score 1):

You have the syntax incorrect.  It should be:

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(200);

for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
    if (check) {
        es.submit(() -> callTrueAPI());
    } else {
        es.submit(() -> callFalseAPI());
    }
}

es.shutdown();
```

After the `shutdown`, the thread pool will *continue until all tasks have completed*.  If you want to wait until the tasks complete, call `awaitTermination` after the `shutdown` call.

---

There is a problem with this approach.  You are actually creating a pool with 200 threads, and then destroying the threads (then the pool shuts down).  This is expensive in both CPU and memory.  If you want to do this more efficiently (in terms of client side resources):

1. Use a smaller thread pool (!)
2. Recycle the pool ... though that will involve using some other method to wait for the tasks to complete.

---

Assuming that the REST calls are going to another service / process, then you can probably launch more threads than you have cores, and have them proceed in parallel.  However, the remote service probably has a limit on the number of simultaneous requests it can perform, so the 200 requests are liable to "back up" in the server's input queue, possibly leading to request timeouts, 5xx errors and so on.   Therefore, firing off 200 requests at once is not likely to be good for overall throughput.

And if you are doing this as a stress test, there are more realistic ways to do it; see @Karol's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have 200 CPU cores you won't be able to send 200 requests at the exact same moment. At the very least Java threads won't be able to execute simultaneously. If you have a regular CPU with 4 cores you most likely can achieve better results by having 4 worker threads that will send the request 50 times each, you will waste less cycles on context switching.

It might be easier to use [Apache JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/) or [Gatling](https://gatling.io/) to create a proper test plan with ramp-up and down period to simulate the traffic you need. These tools were build for the exact purpose you are describing and there are great examples available.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more compact version for Java version >= 8:

```
    ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(200);

    IntStream.range(0, 200).forEach((i) -> es.submit(() -> check ? callTrueAPI() : callFalseAPI()));

    es.shutdown();
```